# Represent JSON as an array of objects in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I would like to create a JSON string as an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "alertid": "1",
        "alerttext": "This is test",
        "alertdate": "2010-02-11 09:03:40"
    },
    {
        "alertid": "2",
        "alerttext": "Another alert",
        "alertdate": "2010-02-11 09:11:04"
    }
]
```

The JAVA JSON objects put method looks like this: jsonObject.put(String key, Collection value);

When I enter my key and collection, my json looks like this:

```
{
    "JSONObject": [
        {
            "alertid": "1",
            "alerttext": "This is test",
            "alertdate": "2010-02-11 09:03:40"
        },
        {
            "alertid": "2",
            "alerttext": "Another alert",
            "alertdate": "2010-02-11 09:11:04"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get my json string to look like the first string when I am constrained to the signature of the put method?

Comment: Can you post your example class? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the net.sf.json library, make yourself a JSONArray and put JSONObjects in it instead.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("alertid","1");

array.add(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `JSONArray` that you can then fill with `JSONObject`'s

Try something like this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
for (JSONObject item : collection)
{
    arr.put(item);
}
```

Or, if you already have a Collection of `JSONObject`'s, you can simply write:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(yourFancyCollection);
```

Then, `arr.toString()` will look like you asked.